# Getting HTML to render <!= and !> tags

Tags: html, tags, markup

I need to use the `<!= ... !>` tags in my code as part of a a jQuery plugin but Chrome is displaying it as  `<!--= ... !-->`, presumably because it thinks it's a malformed comment.

Is there a way of forcing browsers to print the tags as is, allowing for the jQuery plugin to work properly?

Comment: Looks like template tags, which plugin?

Comment: Yes, they are template tags for the jQuery Feeds plugin: https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds

Comment: Does this render for you? http://jsfiddle.net/zazvs/5/

Comment: Yes! Though it loads some of my tags incorrectly: http://jsfiddle.net/zazvs/7/ Link should be an image link and description doesn't load. The RSS is here: http://www.comfyshoulderrest.com/scrape.php?id=1 But this is very close to what I want to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way of doing this and it is by using the ANSI code for them. for example you can try this:

```
&lt;!--= ... !--&gt;
```

The above HTML will be rendered as:

```
<!--= ... !-->
```

Using this method, you can convert the part of the code to ANSI code, by which Browser won't confuse it with a comment and will display it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried using ASCII but that simply prints it out and still isn't picked up by the jQuery plugin because it renders as `"<!= ... !>"` rather than simply `<!= ... !>`.

Comment: @user3423062 is it possible you are using `.text()` in your jQuery? If so use `.html()`. Might be barking up the wrong tree but it's what popped into my head when reading your comment.

Comment: @martincarlin87 my function is `$('div.feed').append($fragment);` if that's useful, and I've looked in the plugin source code and it doesn't use `.text()` at any point.

Comment: It doesn't matter, whether the plugin author have used the `.text()` method or not. Ever long there is a jQuery plugin, you can use the methods of the API. And the code you're having would append the value of `$fragment` in the `div` with class feed. Check for the value in that variable...

Comment: As in, `window.console&&console.log($fragment);`?

Comment: What are you trying to do brother? O.o Do you even know what you're doing?

Comment: This won't give you one. Please try to learn the basics of jQuery! :) I would advise you to do that first...